# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I know this question looks like repeated, but I really read a lot but doesn't solve the problem.

I want to echo the last 10 rows in sql and I get this error.

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\rock\fyp\postAdv.php on line 10

THE Event: 

THE Date:

THE Time:

THE Venue:

Note:
```

the php file is

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("rock","mido","1234","fyp");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 $start = 10;
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $start,10");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ;

 {

  echo "<br><h4> " . "THE Event:  " . $row['EventName'] . "</br>";
  echo "<h4>" . "THE DATE:  " . $row['Date'] ;
  echo "<h4>" . "THE TIME:  " . $row['Time'] ;
  echo "<h4>" . "THE Venue:  " . $row['Venue'] ;
  echo "<h4>" . "Note:  " . $row['Note'] ;

  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You didn't initialize `$start` anywhere. Thus your query fails.

Comment: Since you only want the last 10, remove `$start,` so it is just `LIMIT 10`. If you are going to paginate in the future, leave it in, but initialize it before your query -> `$start = 0`

Comment: done initialize `$start` the result its show me only where the start is

Comment: Change `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ;` to `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` as right now you are only returning 1 row with `mysqli_fetch_array()`, where you want to loop through each `mysqli_fetch_array()` in a `while()` loop

Comment: @sean I changed but the result went blank. nothing even the echo

Comment: Then you most likely have a syntax error. Make sure that it is `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  { echo ...`. Make sure there is not a semi colon `;` between the closing `)` and the opening `{`

Comment: This error happened for me when when I was connecting to wrong data base, the connection was successful but the tables were not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $start = 1 before your query try again.

```
$start = 1;
```

Comment: `$start = 1` will return the 2nd set of 10, probably want `$start = 0` as OP wants the last 10 (1st Set with `DESC`).

Comment: I set `$start = 1` and its shows only the 1st row

Answer (score 2):

`$result` is a boolean because the query you are executing is failing! A failed query gives off boolean `'false'`.

Check you query. Try setting $start with a value before using it in your query.